# I am trying to find a solution to a spacing issue between two div's

Tags: css

This question is totally edited from ground up. Being new was not sure how to ask first time.

So here is a much more simple explanation. My css is causing two of my div's to separate on the page. This only happens if the code is set as block instead of table. It is the only div with this issue. Not sure if the issue is direct or if it is inherited. Can post entire code and html if necessary.

Granted setting as table would fix the spacing but it breaks my responsive image code.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is the css with the issue:

```
#wrapper  {
max-width: 1190px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background : #A8884D;
}

#content {
width : 80%;
margin-top: -20px;   /* This is my work around.*/
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
border-right:  1px solid black; 
border-left: 1px solid black;
background : #A8884D;
}

.center_text{
max-width: 700px;
display: block;     /* This is the troublesome line*/
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Here is the effected html layout structure:
The wrapper is the main parent. The header, navbar and content sit inside the parent and the class center_text sits inside of the content div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header_logo">Logo Here</div>
<div id="navbar">CSS menu here</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="center_text"></div>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

The content div is the one that pulls away from the header_logo div.

Thank You and hope this is a better explanation.

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net demo is worth a thousand words. Or roughly what's up there. ;-)

Comment: can you please post code snippets on a sandbox site such as http://cssdeck.com/labs

Comment: code > story about problem

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the comments. When I got -2 for effort right out of the box I was worried. I know the question was long but the rules said to be through.  Anyway Yes I can make code available. I can even place the entire style sheet and html template along with the text of the problem on my site to make available if that is acceptable with the community. I have nothing to hide with my work at all at therr no propriety info included. I am learning with help and if someone sees something they like great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my own answer to the above problem.

I honestly can not say what the original issue was, but when I changed from a  div based layout to HTML5 layout code and simply changing that corrected the issue.